# Difficulty in displaying Json objects in arrays

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

When the page is loading for the first time, it`s working fine and displaying the data.
When I am doing a search the data returned are

> "[{"ID":358,"Name":"Test,"Client":{"ID":160,"Name":"Client1"},"HasUsers":false}]", but i`m having the message error:
>
> Client is not defined

I am having the following piece of code:

In my View

```
   <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr>
    
    <td>${Client.Name}</td>
    <td>${Name}</td>
</tr>
</script>
```

---

code to bind

```
    success: function (data) {                              
                  $("#myTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#dataBody");            
            },
```

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: What code are you using to bind the data to the template?

Comment: are those quotes added as part of the error? as in is it a String response and not an Object type?

Comment: please see the code above to bind the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't not seem right. it should be

```
[{"ID":358,"Name":"Test","Client":{"ID":160,"Name":"Client1"},"HasUsers":false}]
```

instead of

```
[{"ID":358,"Name":"Test,"Client":{"ID":160,"Name":"Client1"},"HasUsers":false}]
```

`"Test,` should be `"Test",` which is what is messing with Client, probably.